# calling expect script functions inside shell script

Tags: bash, shell, expect

- I am very new to tcl programming. I am trying to write a expect script as a function inside shell script
- Now the shell function which is used has a set of expect commands to be executed.
- These expect commands can be clubbed into a small expect function and needs to be used as a sub-function inside shell function

I have used the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
function auto_run
{
/usr/bin/expect<<EOF
#!/usr/bin/expect
proc guest_reboot {} { 
send "reboot\r"
expect "login" {
send "root\r"
expect "word:"
send "1234\r"
}
}
spawn ssh user@$1 
expect {
"active"
spawn ssh root@$1
expect -re "Escape"
send "\r"
expect "#"
guest_reboot
}
 default
{
send "\r"
guest_reboot
}
}
EOF
}
auto_run guest1
```

Comment: You'll need to escape the backslashes: change all `\r` to `\\r` This is not due to Tcl, it's a byproduct of how the expect script is quoted before the shell passes the expect script to `expect`

Comment: Aside from the issue Glenn raised, what exactly is your question here?

Comment: Unless you have a real need to use bash, this would be better as a pure expect script. You can change the first line to `#!/usr/bin/expect -f` and just write straight expect/tcl code.